# Can't import CSS from Swiper using Webpack with error "Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' You may need an appropriate loader"

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass, webpack-loader

I have a project using SCSS. In this project a minified CSS file is generated during compilation. Now I wanted to add [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/) to the project. So I tried to import the correspodning styles before my styles in `index.js`. Unfortunately I get an error during compillation:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.css 13:0
> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (13:0)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

This is how my `index.js` looks:

```
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
import '../styles/styles.scss';
import Swiper from 'swiper';
```

This is how my `webpack.config.js` looks:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/index.js',

  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },

  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'styles.css'
    }),
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              url: false,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

*What do I need to change in order to make it work?*

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `node_modules` excluded in your webpack config. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following code to the `webpack.config.js` file:

```js
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a an incorrect path for importing the styles.

For finding the appropriate path based on version of swiper, go to `node_modules` and find the `swiper` folder. Then open up `package.json` file and look for `exports` field. there you can find what should be the import path of the corresponding module.

For example for Pagination and Navigation I have

```
"exports": {
     "./core": "./swiper.esm.js",
     "./css/navigation": "./modules/navigation/navigation.min.css",
     "./css/pagination": "./modules/pagination/pagination.min.css",
     /// ...
}
```

So import paths will be

```
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
```